# Is there any rule for differentiating between the endings "th" and "ht"?

Tags: differences, orthography, consonants, digraphs

Some words end in *th* (*length*, *width*), and others end in *ht* (*height*, *fight*, *tonight*, *caught*).

I sometimes have difficulties in spelling such words because I don't know which ending to choose.
Is there *any* rule or pattern (even localized) in choosing one or the other?

Comment: Hint: *-ight*, not just *-ht*.

Comment: @RegDwight Interesting, I added "caught"...I just misspelled RegDwigth

Comment: Well, you can add even more things on top of that, but the real culprit is still *gh*. A good answer will point out why it's there, even though (there it is again, thou*gh*) it's not pronounced.

Comment: very good question, dude!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the two sets of words that you mentioned end with different sounds. The ones ending in *th* all have the [θ] sound, which is formed by putting the tip of the tongue between the front teeth and blowing. The ones ending in *ht* all have the [t] sound (or some allophonic variant thereof). If you're not a native speaker of English, you might have difficulty producing the [θ] sound or distinguishing it from [t], but for native speakers of English the distinction is perfectly clear, and so this problem never arises.

The secondary issue is that of spelling, as you find *th* and *ht* confusing. This is a matter of mis-parsing some common English digraphs. When attempting to read those words, you shouldn't take *h* and *t* together, but rather *g* and *h* together, as the digraph *gh* is pretty common in English, and is usually silent when it's not at the beginning of a word. (In a few words it's pronounced as [f].) In other words, whenever you see *gh* in words like this, you should completely ignore the *gh*, and read the words in your example as *heit, tonit(e), fit(e), caut*, etc. The fact that the *h* is next to the *t* is irrelevant, since the *h* is really part of the silent digraph *gh*.

A final, confusing issue is that a few words ending in -t are sometimes (mis)pronounced as if they ended in -th. For example, the word *height* in proper speech is approximately [hait], but it's often pronounced something like [haitθ]. This is due to influence by other words denoting qualities of measurement (*length, width, depth*) which all end in [θ].

Comment: So if we have a "g" before the last 2 letters, it is followed by "ht". Exception: "ngth" (length, strength), where "g" is not silent. Otherwise, the word ends with "th". Notable exception: yacht. I have used http://www.morewords.com/

Comment: @BogdanLataianu, I think you're still fixating on an irrelevant detail. Having "g" before the last two letters doesn't mean anything at all, and pretty much anything might follow. Consider *ugly*, *angry*, *begin*, *bragged*, or any number of other things. The important thing is the combination *gh*, which is always silent (unless it's at the beginning of the word).

Comment: I understood your point. It then remains to be aware that the "g" in *strength, length* are not silent. I noticed that "ch" plays the role of silent "gh" in *yacht*.

Comment: FYI: regarding "length, width, depth which all end in [θ]" - see [heighth](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/169597/68102), really

Comment: Thank you! For a non-native who spend most of the time reading rather than hearing English, these words have always been cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

1. I think your examples are backwards.
2. Any word ending with a -th spelling ends with a th sound

To make a th sound, trap your tongue between your upper and lower front teeth, blow gently, and release the tongue.  To make a t sound, put the tip of your tongue against the ridge just behind your upper front teeth and blow gently.

I notice that sounds involving biting the tongue or lower lip are the hardest for speakers of Asian languages to get right.  I think it's solely a feature of European languages.  A Bangkok cab driver once offered to get me a ride in a whoa-whoa.  It wasn't until he explained that it was a Swedish car that I figured out what the heck he was talking about.

Comment: I don't think he was talking about the sounds, but rather about the fact he couldn't remember the spelling when writing them.

Comment: Yeah, it might be a psychological effect. Since I make a dental "t" (as in my native language), instead of an alveolar, this error persists in spelling too. @Malvolio made me understand that.

Comment: @Malvolio I would question your method of pronouncing a `t`.  You produced a small burst of air similar to when making a `k` sound, you don't blow.  Very different from the blowing for `th` anyways.

Comment: @Malvolio @Matthew Read: To be exact, you block the air-flow for a moment (when the tongue is touching behind the teeth) and you release it soon after it, check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_plosive).

Comment: @Bogdan -- if I sounded intolerant, I apologize, sincerely.  I don't speak (for example -- guessing from your name) Croatian *at all*.  Like Korben Dallas (qv), I only speak two languages: English and bad English; so I respect anyone who can achieve any fluency in any but his mother tongue.

Answer (score 1):

Noticed a pattern with the vowel +

e.g. weight , height and caught (vowel + g)

as opposed to

length and width (no vowel + g)