# What's with the 'heigth' pandemic?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, historical-change, pronunciation-vs-spelling, variants

Recently I've noticed that many people are pronouncing the word 'height' as

> /haiθ/

That's right, **heigth**.

I've only ever heard this pronunciation mistake in the last few years. Maybe it's just an issue in Texas? Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: It's *heighth*, not *heigth*. A [declining usage](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=heighth&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), where Texas seems to be a couple of centuries behind the rest of us.

Comment: I don't get it...is it the pronunciation or the spelling that's in question here? And if the pronunciation, what exactly is it? 'hie - t - th' or 'hie - th' or 'hie- th -t' or something else?

Comment: @Mitch Pronounciation (see tag) and 'hie - th'

Comment: Related question [/is-there-any-rule-for-differentiating-between-the-endings-th-and-ht](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24524/is-there-any-rule-for-differentiating-between-the-endings-th-and-ht)

Comment: I remember many years ago being told off for criticising my PE teacher's frequent use of *heighth*, because he is Welsh and that's just how *height* is pronounced in Wales. I don't know how accurate that is.

Comment: I've known someone from California who has this problem; I've known plenty of Welsh people who don't.

Comment: Is that even a word? Is it not suppose to be `height`? I tried Googling it, and it just changed the word to `height`.

Comment: I still don't get this. I don't know what the pronunciation you're talking about because the spelling is so non-standard. Can anyone clarify? Is it /haiθ/ ?

Comment: The Texas pronunciation is not /haiθ/, but /haitθ/ (or /hait̪ʰ/ might be more accurate).

Comment: I used to work for a map-making company in Alabama. I had a manager who would always say "heigth, length, and width". A few others would do likewise.

Comment: @MattЭллен *Heighth* is not wrong; see below.

Comment: I just want to second MετάEd's observation about the pronunciation /haitθ/. I grew up in southeast Texas (Corpus Christi and Houston) and I don't remember ever having heard the pronunciation /haiθ/. Among speakers—both white and black—who used the θ sound at all (and they were a small, but by no means negligible minority), it came after a _t_ that was every bit as distinct as the _d_ in _width_.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## *Heighth* is no error

It is a misunderstanding that the spelling or pronunciation of *heighth* is an illiterate and uneducated error.  Although many wrongly consider it such, history is not on their side, nor are the better dictionaries.

Despite how in particular over the last century the *heighth* spelling has come to be stigmatized, *heighth* is a perfectly legitimate word of ancient lineage.   It was used not only by Shakespeare and Milton, but even by Charles Dickens, who wrote considerably later than the first two.

The spelling that is no longer used is *hight*, although it was once common.  Interestingly, Shakespeare variously employed not only *height* and *heighth* but also *hight*, depending on the work:

> - **1591** Shaks. *Two Gentlemen from Verona*, ɪᴠ. iv. 169 — I know she is about my **height**.
> - **1594** Shaks. *Richard III*, ɪ. iii. 41 — I feare our happinesse is at the **height**.
> - *circa* **1600** Shaks. *Sonnet xxxii* — Exceeded by the **hight** of happier men.
> - **1606** Shaks. *Anthony & Cleopatra* ɪɪɪ. x. 21 — Anthony..Leauing the Fight in **heighth**, flyes after her.
> - **1606** Shaks. *Troilus & Cressida*, ᴠ. i. 3 — Let vs Feast him to the **hight**.
> - **1613** Shaks. *Henry VIII*, ɪ. ii. 214 — By day and night Hee’s Traytor to th’ **height**.

Editions of *Anthony & Cleopatra* with normalized spellings now generally read:

> The noble ruin of her magic, Antony,
>   Claps on his sea-wing and, like a doting mallard
>   Leaving the fight in **height**, flies after her.
>   I never saw an action of such shame.
>   Experience, manhood, honor, ne’er before
>   Did violate so itself.

The thing to understand, though, is that this is not some spelling that died out when the reign of Elizabeth I came to an end.  [It remained in use by writers of unimpeachable integrity](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22heighth%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) up through the 19<sup>th</sup> century and sometimes even into the early 20<sup>th</sup>.

All three forms of the word — *height, heighth, hight* — were long used, but in truth, only the last of those has completely fallen away. For while the OED no longer admits *hight* as a modern spelling, **it does present both *height* and *heighth* as admissible variants,** with *-th* listed second. In its rather long etymology section on this word, it observes (bold emphasis mine):

> In ME.
>   the forms in *-t* were predominant in the north, and since
>   1500 have increasingly prevailed in the literary language; **though
>   *heighth*, *highth* were abundant in southern writers
>   till the 18th c., and are still affected by some.**

So if you don’t mind being falsely accused of being wrong, or perhaps with somewhat stronger evidence of writing in an affected manner, go ahead and use it. After all, Microsoft doesn’t know everything about English, so you should never trust its software in matters of writing. :)

Here sorted by date are the OED citations for the *heighth* spelling, excepting only those already given:

> - **1548** **Hall** *Chron., Hen. VIII*, 77 — The same Trees were..in heighth from the foote to the toppe .xxxiiii. foote of assise.
> - **1590** **Sir J. Smyth** *Disc. Weapons* 18 b, — Bullets for the field being smaller and lower..than the heighths of the peeces by a bore.
> - **1611** **B. Jonson** *Catiline* **iii.** iv, — The heighth of wickednesse.
> - **1672** **Bp. Patrick** *Dev. Chr.* (1676) 258 — O the heighth, the depth, the breadth of thy love in Christ Jesus.
> - **1697** **Dampier** *Voy.* I. 370 — Now was the heighth of the Easterly Monsoon.
> - **1704** in B. Church *Hist. Philip’s War* (1867) II. 164 — Carrying the Remainder into Captivity in the heighth of Winter.
> - **1714** **Swift** *Pres. St. Affairs* Wks. 1755 II. **i.** 210 — Those who professed the heighth of what is called the church principle.
> - **1756** **Burke** *Subl. & B.* **ii.** x, — The Medium betwixt an excessive length or heighth and a short or broken quantity.
> - **1762** *Gentl. Mag.* 142 — To such a heighth is licentiousness risen.
> - **1765** **T. Hutchinson** *Hist. Mass.* I. 57 — Carrying antinomianism to the heighth.
> - **1809** **Roland** *Fencing* 22 — It depends on the person’s heighth.
> - **1918** **H. Bindloss** *Agatha’s Fortune* xxv, — It was hardly a range of hills, but rather what prospectors call a ‘heighth’ of land.

## What the Dickens!

But that’s not all!  Consider the Charles Dickens story “Doctor Marigold’s Prescriptions”, published in 1865:

> The doctor having accepted a tea-tray, you’ll guess that my father was a Cheap Jack before me.  You are right.  He was.  It was a pretty tray.  It represented a large lady going along a serpentining up-hill gravel-walk, to attend a little church.  Two swans had likewise come astray with the same intentions.  When I call her a large lady, I don’t mean in point of breadth, for there she fell below my views, but she more than made it up in heighth; her heighth and slimness was—in short THE heighth of both.

As you see, that sounds perfectly fine.  Please note that modern editions of that work are **not** respelled as so often now occurs with Shakespeare.  *Heighth* is retained just as Dickens wrote it.

Notice also how in the Dickens citation, *heighth* has a distinct advantage when used in conjunction with *breadth* or *length*, since now one retains a certain parallelism of form that would be lost were it spelled *height*.

### Recommendation

That said, I personally would not **in general** recommend writing *heighth* unless you are writing a period piece. I say this not out of correctness, but to fend off the hypercorrective efforts of those with less education, given how few today realize its actual provenance and legitimacy.

If you ***do*** choose to use *heighth*, however, you should probably be prepared to back up your use at the very least with **the OED, which attaches *no stigma* to that spelling,** and probably with citations from other writers of note.

Comment: This is an incredibly scholarly post (bravo; brilliant).  But all you're saying is **"Funnily enough, heighth is an archaic pronunciation."**  But (no offence) ... so what?  I could give 1000 examples of archaic pronunciations that are utterly, hopelessly, wrong today (I'm sure you could give 10,000 examples!)

Comment: @JoeBlow I’m afraid that you’ve quite missed the point; please **see the title** of my posting. Although this is a venerable pronunciation of ancient pedigree, it is absolutely not “utterly, hopelessly, wrong” today. The OED attaches no more stigma to the spelling or pronunciation that to say “and is still affected by some today”.  ***Heighth* is not marked obsolete, archaic, dialectal, nor vulgar** — all appellations they do not hesitate to use for words that merit them. This one does not.

Comment: I guess I could rephrase then -- You're saying "Funnily enough, heighth is an archaic pronunciation which in my opinion is still active; the OED agrees with me."  As I said to another writer below, and I could say to you, "You and I "really" know what decimate, apocryphal and myriad mean, but all three have been turned on their head." All three would have "our" definition in the OED.

Comment: I was interested to see a couple reports below from folks pointing out that their Aunt, etc, has used heigth. Fair enough.  {An interesting point though: I'd guess our OP's route to this question was "aks-English", people who say aks and b[r]ought, are now saying heigth: ie, I'd guess it's just a coincidence that "heigth" is a ye olde spelling. [As if for example there was really a word aks.]}

Comment: {And just BTW, in engineering I would use "heigth" as an iterator index over objects of different heights! :) example, you're the 3rd tallest, your heigth is "3".}

Comment: There are a couple of answers here that I'd be happy to award the bounty to. But I can't split it, and this is clearly the most deserving, so you get it.

Comment: @JoeBlow: funnily enough, "aks" instead of "ask" also has a long history, but I agree with your point that the historical use of these words has little relevance to how they are perceived today.

Comment: I don't find this answer satisfying.  The issue as stated in the question is regarding pronunciation.  Okay so "heighth" is not wrong. However I don't believe that the people who are pronouncing "heighth" are spelling it that way in their day-to-day lives.  I would wager that their own spelling is at odds with their pronunciation.  This disconnect between their own spelling and their own pronunciation gives the feeling that it is somehow slightly uneducated.

Comment: You seem to imply that education and use of the word "heighth" are uncorrelated. However, I'd wager good money that P(educated | uses heighth more often than height) is quite low. That's been my experience, in any case.

Comment: How's that with _weight_? Is there a similar case of .. _weighth_?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603194/2085).

Answer (score 15):

Well, it seems that the misconception regarding the spelling/pronunciation is due to some confusion regarding dimension-related words:

- Dep*th*
- Wid*th*
- Bread*th*

And....

- Height

I have [some](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=615251) [links](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000285.htm) that would suggest that this is the reason for the misuse.

Comment: And... Weight. That should counteract it! I don't hear people saying *weigth*.

Comment: @Dave:  I think it's because the others are all measurements of length but weight is not. One often talks about height/width/length as a group.

Comment: Height and weight is probably more common

Comment: @Dave:  Height and weight is more common in terms of human proportions, but I'm not sure it's more common in general.  I don't see people saying "Height(h) and weight", but I do see them saying "Length and height(h)."   But maybe it's just a regional thing.

Comment: ’Tisn’t actually a “misuse”, *per se*.  [See below](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/169597).

Comment: I've used heighth my entire life and this is the first I've heard of it being questioned. I definitely use it collocated with length and breadth. And I use it in idiomatic ways where the hard /t/ pronunciation would strike me as odd - *The heighth of folly*, *the heighth of the airplane* or the *heighth of the bridge*. Do others really say *height of the airplane*? Having said all this, my family is quite spread-out generation-wise, and my antecedents came from some language backwaters. Also, the early European settlers to this area were largely Welsh and Scot.

Answer (score 8):

On his World Wide Words website, etymologist Michael Quinion describes the phenomenon and its origins here:

http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-hei1.htm

He sums up its current status thus:

> Because of its odd history, we can hardly argue that highth is truly an error, more an archaism. Though nearly everyone now spells it height, it’s not that uncommon to hear it said as /haɪtθ/ [1] among educated people in North America, and some authorities there consider it to be a permissible variant.

[1] Pronunciation help is provided here:

http://www.worldwidewords.org/pronguide.htm

Answer (score 6):

A couple of points: why do you assume it to be a mispronunciation? It used to be common in my youth in New Zealand, where we speak British English. It started to fall out of use around the end of World War Two, when American English became popular, due mainly to  Hollywood influences. It goes back at least as far as 1588.

Comment: Please qualify your statement with some evidence. See the comments below the question.

Answer (score 2):

Agree that its not a modern phenomenon - I remember *heighth* from Anthony Burgess' A Clockwork Orange. In the first chapter, Alex says:

> There were three devotchkas sitting at the counter all together, but
>   there were four of us malchicks and it was usually like one for all
>   and all for one. These sharps were dressed in the **heighth** of fashion
>   too, with purple and green and orange wigs on their gullivers, each
>   one not costing less than three or four weeks of those sharps' wages,
>   I should reckon, and make-up to match ...

Burgess 'created' [Nadsat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nadsat) for the novel, using Russian and Polari (c.f. this [article](http://www.theguardian.com/books/booksblog/2012/may/14/happy-birthday-a-clockwork-orange) from The Guardian), I wonder if his usage stems from either of those.

Answer (score -1):

I feel it is a "dialectical variant" and there are sufficient proofs that it is simply a popular mispronunciation the educated population have grown too tired of correcting. Just because a mispronunciation has become commonly used doesn't make it a legitimate word.

"Heighth" is a chiefly dialectal variant of "height".