# What is the ‘‑ht vs ‑th’ grammar or spelling rule?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, suffixes, derivational-morphology, is-it-a-rule

Some words end with *‑th* while others end with *‑ht*.  For example:

1. *Height, weight, thought, drought, sleight, sight* all end with *‑ht*.
2. *Length, width, breadth, depth, wealth, girth, dearth* all end with *‑th*.

Is there any rule I can use so I can know whether I should put *‑th* or *‑ht* at the end of a given word?

Comment: One thing you might want to consider in your research is that your "ht"-ending words are all "ght"-ending words.

Comment: One rule might be that they sound completely different. :p

Answer (score 13):

There isn't an ending *-ht* in English; rather, your first set of examples use the ending *-t*. The <gh> comes from the stem; in several of your examples this isn't obvious because related words (*dry*, *sly*, *see*) are no longer spelled with <gh>, but since the <gh> is silent in Modern English, perhaps that shouldn't surprise us. (In the case of *thought*, the related word *think* never had <gh>; rather, the <gh> of *thought* corresponds to the /k/ of *think*.)

As for *-th* vs. *-t* . . . you're probably aware that there are a few endings that are always *-th* (e.g. the ordinal ending as in *eighth*) and a few endings that are always *-t* (e.g. the past-tense ending as in *slept*), but for the ending that you're interested in, the alternation between *-th* and *-t* has to do with the sound that preceded it in Old English or Middle English; *-th* was the usual form, but *-t* was used after fricatives, including the /h/ sound that eventually disappeared from pronunciation but left us with the written <gh>. (Some non-/h/ examples are *theft* and *thrift*.)

Sources:

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-th#English
- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-t#English
- https://www.etymonline.com/word/thought
- https://www.etymonline.com/word/drought
- https://www.etymonline.com/word/sleight
- https://www.etymonline.com/word/sight